# JQuery position() returns zeros in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, safari

I use `position()` and `getBoundingClientRect()` to determine if svg object is visible in viewport. Works perfectly well in Chrome, Firefox and EDGE but not in Safari.

`obj.position()` always returns `{top: 0, left: 0}` in Safari.

What could be wrong?

```
options.elements.forEach(function (item) {                        
    let obj = jQuery("#" + item);

    if (!!obj && !!obj[0]) {
        let position = obj.position();
        let box = obj[0].getBoundingClientRect()

        if (!!position) {
            if (position.left <= left + width &&
                position.left + box.width >= left &&
                position.top <= top + height &&
                position.top + box.height >= top)
                 onscreen.push(item);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is part of HTML. I omitted contents of 'd' of svg

```
<div id="svgmap">
<svg id="svg">
<g id="R918">
    <path d="...." transform="translate(-0.08 0.25)"//>
  </g>
  <g id="C902J">
    <path d="...."  transform="translate(-0.08 0.25)"/>
  </g>
  <g id="C9002I">
    <path d="" transform="translate(-0.08 0.25)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: In SVG you may want to use .getBBox() instead of getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: They are rather different things, getBBox uses the local co-ordinate system, getBoundingClientRect the global one. They are rarely the same except in the most trivial documents.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I didn't figure out why position() is not working in Safari in this particular case but I realized that I don't need to user position() at all. I can get the same data from getBoundingClientRect().left and getBoundingClientRect().top